# create a specific route with systemd-networkd

Tags: routing, ipv6, route, iproute, systemd-networkd

I am trying for days to setup a specific route with systemd-networkd. And it all fails.

```
[Match]
Name=en*

[Network]
DHCP=yes
IPv6PrivacyExtensions=kernel
IPv6AcceptRA=true

[Route]
Destination=2001:470:2099::/48
PreferredSource=2001:470:2099:e2:226:b9ff:fef6:d709
Source=2001:470:2099:e2:226:b9ff:fef6:d709
Metric=256
```

I don't know which is important : the **Source** or **PreferredSource** (I have tried to disable each of parameters, none work). The daemon always say that it cannot set the route. It's invalid. But I don't have more precision.

What I wish to acheive is to set a route in the same way as :

```
ip -6 route add 2001:470:2099::/48 src 2001:470:2099:e2:226:b9ff:fef6:d709 dev eno1 metric 128
```

So here, it's the source address of the route that is important. All that goes to this /48 network should use this address.

Problem is also to assure the route surpass the normal /64 route, as it's this:

```
 2001:470:2099:e2::/64 dev eno1  proto kernel  metric 256  expires 3483sec pref medium
 fe80::/64 dev eno1  proto kernel  metric 256  pref medium
 default via fe80::226:b9ff:fef6:d709 dev eno1  proto ra  metric 1024  expires 483sec hoplimit 255 pref medium
```

What should I do ?

Thank you.